# Is there a better way to call ref.current.scrollIntoView() from a child component to scroll to a ref in its parent?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on my first ReactJS/TypeScript project.

All I want to do is call `ref.current.scrollIntoView()` from a child component to scroll to a ref in its parent.

I've got it working using a fairly ugly if statement in the `onClick` handler, `scrollTest()`, to keep TypeScript happy. Hoping there's a cleaner way of doing this.

Bonus points if there's a way to avoid setting `Sections.displayname` explicitly.

```
import {
  Container,
  Grid,
  Link,
  Typography
} from '@material-ui/core'

import React, { ReactElement } from 'react'

const Section = (
  {
    children
  }: {
    children: React.ReactNode
  }
): ReactElement => {
  return(
    <>
      <Grid container style={{minHeight: "100vh"}}>
        <Grid item>
          {children}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  )
}

const Sections = React.forwardRef<HTMLElement>((_, ref): ReactElement => {
  const scrollTest = (): void => {
    if (ref && "current" in ref && ref.current) {
      ref.current.scrollIntoView()
    }
  }

  const sections = [
    <>
      <Typography paragraph variant="h3">
        <Link onClick={scrollTest}>Scroll to footer</Link>
      </Typography>
    </>
  ].map((section, index) => {
    return(
      <Section key={index}>
        {section}
      </Section>
    )
  })

  return(<>{sections}</>)
})

Sections.displayName = 'Sections'

export default function Test(): ReactElement {
  const footerRef = React.useRef<HTMLElement>(null)

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Sections ref={footerRef} />
        <Grid
          component="footer"
          container
          ref={footerRef}
        >
          <Grid>
            <Typography paragraph>
              Footer
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: This looks wrong – you're passing `ref={footerRef}` to two different components at the same time. I would pass it to `Sections` as a regular prop instead of using `forwardRef`.

Comment: Wow, fast response. I thought `ref` sets it for `Grid` but for `Sections` it forwards that ref for the component to use because it's using `forwardRef()`. Not sure what the technical difference would be if it's passed as a prop?

Comment: What you could do is create a function in the parent component and then pass the function down to the child. This way you don't need to forward ref and the logic can live closer to the definition.

Comment: For class components, the ref prop has a special behavior provided by React. With function components, you have to use forwardRef to implement the desired behavior yourself (usually with useImperativeHandle and/or passing the ref into an inner component that you render). So I think your usage of it is not technically wrong, but it is unusual, and if you use a regular prop you won't need the forwardRef and strange type checking.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give those suggestions a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on jtbandes’ comments I got the following:

```
import {
  Container,
  Grid,
  Link,
  Typography
} from '@material-ui/core'

import React, { ReactElement } from 'react'

const Section = (
  {
    children
  }: {
    children: React.ReactNode
  }
): ReactElement => {
  return(
    <>
      <Grid container style={{minHeight: "100vh"}}>
        <Grid item>
          {children}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  )
}

const Sections = (
  {
    footerRef
  }: {
    footerRef: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>
  }
): ReactElement => {
  const scrollToFooter = (): void => {
      footerRef?.current?.scrollIntoView()
  }

  const sections = [
    <>
      <Typography paragraph variant="h3">
        <Link onClick={scrollToFooter}>Scroll to footer</Link>
      </Typography>
    </>
  ].map((section, index) => {
    return(
      <Section key={index}>
        {section}
      </Section>
    )
  })

  return(<>{sections}</>)
}

export default function Test(): ReactElement {
  const footerRef = React.useRef<HTMLElement>(null)

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Sections footerRef={footerRef} />
        <Grid
          component="footer"
          container
          ref={footerRef}
        >
          <Grid>
            <Typography paragraph>
              Footer
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}
```

Don't know why but without `forwardRef()` the safe operator, `?`, now works with both the `RefObject` and `current` making the `if` statement redundant.

Removing `forwardRef()` also removes the need to set `displayname` explicitly, bonus points given.

Considered Dennis Matinez’s suggestion but it made more sense to me to have the click handler in the same component as the source of the click event.